# Why is overflow-hidden not working (with 3d css transformation)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, styling

I am making a swipeable grid. In the outer div I contain the grid. The inner div will contain the grid items, as a flex box. Using the mouse events, I will change the value of `offsetX` so that the inner div is translated by some x value, to make everything swipeable. Everything works fine, but the children of the inner div that are outside the outer div still show, I would like them to be hidden. I am styling everything using tailwind.js.

```
<div
  className={cls([
    className,
    "overflow-hidden relative",
    fullWidth ? "w-screen" : "max-w-full",
    paddingY ? `py-${paddingY}` : "py-8",
  ])}
  {...props}
  ref={carouselElementRef}
>
  <div
    className={cls([
      "flex flex-no-wrap overflow-hidden relative min-w-max",
      "touch-pan-y",
      "cursor-grab select-none",
      swiping ? "" : "transition-transform duration-300 ease-out",
    ])}
    onMouseDown={swipe}
    onTouchStart={swipe}
    ref={stageElementRef}
    style={{
      transform: `translate3d(${offsetX}px, 0, 0)`,
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
</div>
```

Other answers for this similar issue said making the parent/child have a `fixed/relative` position would fix it, but that doesn't help. Setting both to `relative`, and to both have `overflow-hidden` does not fix it.